# What happened to the 9 Aes Sedai who tried to destroy a Waygate?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In The Shadow Rising (book 4 of The Wheel of Time series), Loial mentions that:

> "Another attempt she wrote of, by only nine, during the Trolloc Wars, damaged the Gate in such a way that the Aes Sedai were pulled into--- " he cut off, wriggling with embarrassment, and knuckled his wide nose.

Do we ever find out more about that story and what happened to the 9 Aes Sedai and the Waygate? What happened to them and where were they pulled into?

Comment: Into shreds, you say?

Comment: I don't recall this ever being mentioned anywhere else in the books. I would assume they were pulled into the Ways?

Comment: Since even Loial has not read about the remains of that one Waygate that was destroyed by Aes Sedai, I would suspect the attempt did not achieve the desired effect and the whatever they were pulled into stirred Loial's thoughts enough to pull him out of his full-nerd-monologue. I would expect it either was ultimately "into shreds" or some place with no way back, which is probably worse than "into shreds"-